# Unexpected content frames after dismissing sheet and recreating main view

Tags: swiftui

I need to restart my main view when user authorisation has changed. To do that, I simply close all presented views and recreate the main view. Everything works fine except one strange bug. After recreating the view all the subviews on the main view are displayed as expected but the actual frames are shifted and I am not able to click the open sheet button. It is still clickable but in a different area.

[image]

I've created a sample app which reproduces the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    @State var id = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        MainView(onRestartSession: {
            id = UUID()
        })
        .id(id)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var bottomSheetIsPresented: Bool = false

    let onRestartSession: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Open Bottom Sheet") {
                bottomSheetIsPresented.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $bottomSheetIsPresented) {
                BottomSheetView(onRestartSession: {
                    bottomSheetIsPresented = false
                    onRestartSession()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BottomSheetView: View {
    let onRestartSession: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button("Restart Session") {
            onRestartSession()
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the frames not to be shifted.
I can't reproduce this behaviour if:

BottomSheetView is presented as fullScreenCover;

MainView is presented as fullScreenCover;

NavigationView is removed from MainView;

Some other view was presented and dismissed on MainView.

As a temporary solution I present MainView as fullScreenCover but it looks like a hack to me.
I want to know if this is a SwiftUI bug or there is a problem in my code.

UPD:
Reproduced with Xcode 14.2 and Xcode 14.3, iPhone 14 Pro 16.2

Comment: Not seeing any issues. Xcode 14.3.1, iPhone 14 Pro simulator running 16.4.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've reproduced it using Xcode 14.2 and Xcode Version 14.3, iPhone 14 Pro 16.2. I checked it on iOS 16.4 and it seems that they fixed it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with Xcode 14.3.1 and iPhone 14 Pro 16.4 simulator.

Comment: On Different devices frame offsets are different but it is clear in the debug view hierarchy. I've checked it on iOS 17 in Xcode beta 8 they have completely fixed it.